# Schedule and post comments to FaceBook wall using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

i want to develop application like hootsuite . com

Schedule the FaceBook wall using ASP.Net

main question :

once user login in my system then he need to add his facebook user name and password once then how can i store that user's FB username and password because they need to Schedule and post comments to FaceBook wall so every time user will not login

can any once guide step by step ?

i hope you all help me

Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Answer (score 0):

> once user login in my system then he need to add his facebook user name and password once then how can i store that user's FB username and password

This is completely the wrong approach – FB’s policies discourage users to share their login credentials with third-party services, and if your app will be caught asking for those, it will most likely be disabled quickly.

Get access tokens from the users, and use those to post.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/, https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: just need guidance  hwo can i schedule fb post from asp.net

Comment: i did not want to store user password in my system but if want to schedule fb post then where it will be store

Comment: The API offers scheduled posts only for pages, not for users – so if you want to implement scheduled posts for users yourself, you have to make sure your script that makes the post is called at the right time – f.e. via a cronjob, that calls the script periodically and has it look up which posts are to make at that point.

Comment: yes i need scheduled posts only for pages for now can you please where i found API for this ?

Comment: but how user scheduled  his post on page if user not login ?

Comment: User log in to give you access token, as me said to you before, understand?

Comment: can you please give me access token example ? i am still confused . i need to store that token? how much time you that token will be saved ?

Comment: Read the links I posted in my initial answer, please.

Comment: when i connect fb via my system this code generate in url: code=AQBCvLhbkfA2Z0kFUGrwBGwNGLlKPB8jiNsJWz2f9wd87muzWIHE7gyTQ1TFgThOE-zdItnmZmsumj9iuo3DuFbynBuh95aUDIJliFPwRSgOf8rBAjANc_hMneYep68oSAGHwLm2HjuUAsfP_AyvE47pJriI4zN_jlxTjms-RqUudcSx_IyyDrPzDlc9DGNuk1i_UZKpkOhRfofolfzKDw53#_=_


-----is this is celled token ? --this code come every time different thats why i am confused

Comment: Then you are obviously at step 3 of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/ – and now you have to do the next one. (How hard is it to read a page of documentation till the end …?)

Comment: what is difference between " Server-Side Authentication " and " Client-Side Authentication " ? i need to use only " Server-Side Authentication " at this time ?

Comment: Read the documentation about the two kinds of authentication flows for the difference. Which one you chose, is up to you; might depend on what’s easier to handle in your app flow.

Comment: Sorry to ask you lots of basic questions  but i am confused in this code ---

client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
&grant_type=client_credentials

----

In this code what is " client_credentials " ? ... What value i need to pass? for client_credentials ?

Comment: That parameter is to be kept exactly as it is, `grant_type=client_credentials` – it tells the API what exactly you want from it with this call. (Maybe there’s a reason why the put some parts of example address shown there in CAPITAL LETTERS, but _not_ this one? Also, in the paragraph above, it explicitly says what parts you have to fill in yourself in this URL – and grant_type is _not_ among those. A _little bit_ of own thinking might be required at some point when playing with an API …)

Comment: ok token generated successful now i read this token is valid for 60 days? Also i need to store this token in database? or no need to save any-ware ?

Comment: Please get a basic knowledge of writing web applications yourself …

Comment: ok but just can you please tell me is every user have different token or they can only access one application token ? i know still its basic question but if can just tell me then i can go for my next step

Comment: still not success anyone can help on this

Comment: sorry to ask here but when i click ask question then i get this message " Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more." now how can ask?

Comment: ok i am getting some sucess
there is once question
i need to use " access token "
but the question is how can i generate every time new token ?
is access token for generate for every user or its same for all user?
what things i need to store in database ?

Comment: please reopen my account and please guide me ..i am really sorry i have asked lots of basic question. i will try my bset this time please re open my account  and guide me